# How do I implement a Vlookup using a variable declared as Variant?

Tags: excel, vba

I extract a bug number from a column in sheet1.

I then try to look up the associated estimated time in sheet3 (Bug Estimates) via a vLookup. I get Error 2042 (x3 for each value in my loop).

I tried hardcoding the value I'm looking up via the vLookup e.g. 1234.
I tried adding .Value when setting the Range object.
I tried activating the sheet with the lookup data first. 
I tried using Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup.

```vb
    Dim BugID As Variant 
    Dim BugNumber As String 
    Dim BugRange As Variant 
    Dim Points As Variant

    For Each BugID In BugMatches
       BugID = StrConv(BugID, vbLowerCase)
       BugNumber = Trim(Replace(BugID, "bug", ""))
       Set BugRange = Worksheets("Bug Estimates").Range("A2:C5")
       Points = Application.VLookup(BugNumber, BugRange, 1, False)
    Next
```

Comment: How is defined `BugNumber`? Make sure is the same data type as the bug numbers stored in `BugRange`. Also, if you post and example of your input and the expected output, it will help.

Comment: So for example I start with a string in the Cell Bug 1234.  So BugNumber would equal 1234 in this instance.  On my Bug Estimates sheet, in A1 = 1234 and in B1 = 5 so I would expect in the first loop for Points = 5. Thanks.

Comment: Please, do not post additional info as comment. Edit your original question and update it with the new info. Thanks!

Comment: @Dorian Error 2042. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns is right - it seemed to work for me if I used Cint to make sure your are doing a lookup on a number:

```
For Each BugID In BugMatches
       BugID = StrConv(BugID, vbLowerCase)
       BugNumber = Trim(Replace(BugID, "bug", ""))
       Set BugRange = Worksheets("Bug Estimates").Range("A2:C5")
       Points = Application.VLookup(CInt(BugNumber), BugRange, 2, False)
       Debug.Print ("Points=" & Points)
Next
```

but I was only guessing what the data might look like.

Comment: Yes, actually he posted `Dim BugNumber As String ` so `BugNumber` is a string, and the data in the worksheet is, probably, a number

Comment: I seem to be getting some results out now having changed BugNumber to variant (for now) and adding in CInt(BugNumber).  Thank you.